# Prove $\exists!A\Bigr(\mathcal F\subseteq\mathscr P(A)\land\forall B\bigr(\mathcal F\subseteq\mathscr P(B)\rightarrow A\subseteq B\bigr)\Bigr)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

This is exercise $3.7.1$ from the book *How to Prove it* by Velleman $($$2^{nd}$ edition$)$:

Suppose $\mathcal F$ is a family of sets. Prove that there is a unique set $A$ that has the following two properties:

$(a)$ $\mathcal F\subseteq \mathscr P(A)$.

$(b)$ $\forall B\Bigr(\mathcal F\subseteq \mathscr P(B)\rightarrow A\subseteq B\Bigr)$.

Here is my proof:

Existence: Let $\mathcal F$ be an arbitrary family of sets and suppose $A=\bigcup\mathcal F$.

Let $C$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathcal F$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $C$. From $C\in\mathcal F$ and $x\in C$, $x\in\bigcup\mathcal F$ and since $A=\bigcup\mathcal F$, $x\in A$. Thus if $x\in C$ then $x\in A$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $\forall x(x\in C\rightarrow x\in A)$ and so $C\subseteq A$. Ergo $C\in\mathscr P(A)$. Therefore if $C\in\mathcal F$ then $C\in\mathscr P(A)$. Since $C$ is arbitrary, $\forall C\Bigr(C\in\mathcal F\rightarrow C\in\mathscr P(A)\Bigr)$ and so $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathscr P(A)$.

Let $B$ be an arbitrary set such that $\mathcal F\subseteq \mathscr P(B)$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A$. From $\mathcal F\subseteq \mathscr P(B)$ by definition we have $\bigcup\mathcal F\subseteq B$. Since $A=\bigcup \mathcal F$, from $\bigcup\mathcal F\subseteq B$ and $x\in A$ we obtain $x\in B$. Thus if $x\in A$ then $x\in B$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $\forall x(x\in A\rightarrow x\in B)$ and so $A\subseteq B$. Therefore if $\mathcal F\subseteq \mathscr P(B)$ then $A\subseteq B$. Since $B$ is arbitrary, $\forall B\Bigr(\mathcal F\subseteq\mathscr P(B)\rightarrow A\subseteq B\Bigr)$.

Uniqueness: Let $C$ and $D$ be arbitrary sets such that $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathscr P(C)$,
$\mathcal F\subseteq\mathscr P(D)$, $\forall B\Bigr(\mathcal F\subseteq\mathscr P(B)\rightarrow C\subseteq B\Bigr)$, and $\forall B\Bigr(\mathcal F\subseteq\mathscr P(B)\rightarrow D\subseteq B\Bigr)$. From $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathscr P(C)$ and $\forall B\Bigr(\mathcal F\subseteq\mathscr P(B)\rightarrow D\subseteq B\Bigr)$, $D\subseteq C$. From $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathscr P(D)$ and $\forall B\Bigr(\mathcal F\subseteq\mathscr P(B)\rightarrow C\subseteq B\Bigr)$, $C\subseteq D$. Ergo $C=D$.

$Q.E.D.$

Is my proof valid$?$

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Existence is meant to hold for _all_ families $\mathcal F$, so you can't just pick $\mathcal F=\{\varnothing\}$ and be done with it

Comment: @shibai How about now?

Comment: A bit verbose, but otherwise it looks fine now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Your proof looks fine to me. This is strictly speaking not an answer to your question, but perhaps this alternative proof helps provide some insight.)*$%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\leftarrow}
\newcommand{\fa}[2]{\forall #1 \left( #2 \right) }
\newcommand{\ex}[2]{\exists #1 \left( #2 \right) }
\newcommand{\exun}[2]{\exists ! #1 \left( #2 \right) }
\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal F}
\newcommand{\equiv}{\leftrightarrow}
%$

It seems the key insight here is what $\;\F \subseteq \mathscr P(X)\;$ means, and how we can 'pull out' $\;X\;$ from this expression.  The simplest way is to just start calculating, by first expanding the definitions:

$$\calc
    \F \subseteq \mathscr P(X)
\op\equiv\hint{expand definition of subset}
    \fa D {D \in \F \then D \in \mathscr P(X)}
\op\equiv\hint{expand definition of powerset}
    \fa D {D \in \F \then D \subseteq X}
\op\equiv\hint{expand definition of subset}
    \fa D {D \in \F \then \fa z {z \in D \then z \in X}}
\op\equiv\hint{logic: merge quantifications}
    \fa {D,z} {D \in \F \land z \in D \;\then\; z \in X} \tag{*}
\op\equiv\hints{logic -- to simplify in a different way,}\hints{by bringing quantification over $\;D\;$ closer to where it is used,}\hint{keeping $\;X\;$ separate}
    \fa z {\ex D {D \in \F \land z \in D} \;\then\; z \in X}
\op\equiv\hint{definition of union -- to simplify}
    \fa z {z \in \bigcup \F \;\then\; z \in X}
\op\equiv\hint{definition of subset -- to simplify}
    \bigcup \F \subseteq X
\endcalc$$

(Note how $\Ref{*}$ is like a central hinge, connecting the top part which looks at the sets, and the bottom part which looks at the elements in those sets.)

So we discovered that $\;\F \subseteq \mathscr P(X) \;\equiv\; \bigcup \F \subseteq X\;$, and that now makes it simple to prove the statement:

$$\calc
    \exun A {\F \subseteq \mathscr P(A) \;\land\; \fa B {\F \subseteq \mathscr P(B) \then A \subseteq B}}
\op\equiv\hint{using the above property, twice}
    \exun A {\bigcup \F \subseteq A \;\land\; \fa B {\bigcup \F \subseteq B \then A \subseteq B}}
\op\equiv\hint{set theory: basic property of $\;\subseteq\;$, i.e., transitivity}
    \exun A {\bigcup \F \subseteq A \;\land\; A \subseteq \bigcup \F}
\op\equiv\hint{set theory: simplify}
    \exun A {A = \bigcup \F}
\endcalc$$

which is trivially true, and therefore the $\;A\;$ that we were looking for turns out to be $\;\bigcup \F\;$.

$%
\endgroup
%$

Comment: Thank you very much. :$)$

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is not valid.

You are given a family $\mathcal F$ and are supposed to show the existence (and uniqueness) of $A$. Instead, you pick $\mathcal F$ at will.

Comment: I am so sorry. I guess this happens when insomnia hits you and you still try to solve problems instead of reading a book. I edited my answer. Is it correct now?